# Why should I use docker ONBUILD?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

## 1. Scenario **with** `ONBUILD`

#### Base `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3

ONBUILD COPY test.py test.py
```

Obliviously, when we build above `Dockerfile`(`test-image:latest`), the `COPY` wont affected.(The `test.py` not copied)

#### Now onbuild `Dockerfile`

```
FROM test-image:latest
```

Now, when we build above `Dockerfile`, the `COPY` will affect, copies `test.py`

## 2. Scenario without `ONBUILD`

I achieve same thing without use `ONBUILD`

#### Base `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3
```

Above `Dockerfile` build docker image which has `python3` (`test-image2:latest`)

#### Now child docker image `Dockerfile`

```
FROM test-image2:latest
COPY test.py /test.py
```

So, my question is, why should I use `ONBUILD` or when should use? is there any performance difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the answer is simple:  you want to use `ONBUILD` when your parent image has to be used in various children images, so you

1. avoid **repetitions**
2. **contstrain** the user of the image to have `test.py` copied

Answer (score 3):

In general you shouldn't use ONBUILD at all.  Having a later Dockerfile FROM line do something other than simply incorporate its contents violates the principle of least surprise.

If the thing you're trying to do ONBUILD is something like a RUN or ENV instruction, semantically it makes no difference whether you do it in the base image or the derived image.  It will be more efficient if you do it in the base image (once ever, as opposed to once each time a derived image is built).

If you're trying to ONBUILD COPY ... then you're trying to force a specific file to be *on the host system* at the point you run `docker build`, which is a little strange as a consumer.  Docker's [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#onbuild) notes

> Be careful when putting `ADD` or `COPY` in `ONBUILD`. The “onbuild” image fails catastrophically if the new build’s context is missing the resource being added. Adding a separate tag, as recommended above, helps mitigate this by allowing the `Dockerfile` author to make a choice.

As that page notes, if you must use ONBUILD, you should call it out in the image tag so it's clear when you build a Dockerfile FROM that image, something strange is going on.  Most current Docker Hub images don't have `-onbuild` variants at all, even for things like [tomcat](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/) that generally have extremely formulaic uses.

Comment: Wish Google would have this philosophy :/ Their base GCP images have ONBUILDs that run shell scripts!

Comment: If one shouldn't use ONBUILD, why does it exist at all?